# Why $\phi(k)$ does not depend on time in the free particle case?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, time-evolution

In the free particle case, the general solution to the time-dependent Schrödinger equation is:

$$\Psi (x, t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(k) e^{i(kx-\frac{\hbar k^2t}{2m})} dk$$

I do not understand why $\phi(k)$ does not depend on time. I have the idea that $\phi(k)$ is related to the 'envelope' of the wave packet, which travels at the group velocity. So the first logic idea that came to my mind was that the envelope *should* change as time runs, having $\phi(k)$ a time dependence. Why am I wrong?

I am aware of the fact that $\phi(k)$ can be computed using Fourier analysis and that if $\phi(k)$ was time-dependent it would not be possible to compute it using this method. But I am interested in the physical explanation of it.

Comment: $\phi (k)$ is the amplitude of a pure ideal sinusoid, how could that change?

Comment: But the envelope does change in function of time right?

Comment: Have you studied the [Gaussian wavepacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet#Dispersive)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do not understand why ϕ(k) does not depend on time.

The short answer is:

$$\Phi(k,t) = \phi(k)\,e^{-\frac{i\hbar k^2}{2m}t}$$

The long(er) answer is that, for a free particle, momentum eigenstates are also *stationary states*.  That is, a state vector $|\psi_k(t)\rangle$ with definite momentum $p = \hbar k$ has 'trivial' time evolution

$$|\psi_k(t)\rangle = |k\rangle\, e^{-\frac{i\hbar k^2}{2m}t}$$

where $|k\rangle$ is a momentum eigenket with eigenvalue $k$.  Assume a general free particle state vector $|\Psi(t)\rangle$ and express it in terms of the momentum eigenstate basis:

$$|\Psi(t)\rangle = \int\mathrm{d}k\,|k\rangle\,\phi(k)\, e^{-\frac{i\hbar k^2}{2m}t}$$

where

$$\phi(k) \equiv \langle k |\Psi(0)\rangle$$

So, to be clear, $\phi(k)$ is the *amplitude* for finding the particle in the momentum eigenket $|k\rangle$ at time $t = 0$.  Clearly, $\phi(k)$ is *not* a function of time since we evaluating the amplitude at a particular time.

Now, the final step is project all this onto the position basis:

$$\Psi(x,t) = \langle x|\Psi(t)\rangle = \int\mathrm{d}k\,\langle x|k\rangle\,\phi(k)\, e^{-\frac{i\hbar k^2}{2m}t} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\mathrm{d}k\,\phi(k)\,e^{ikx}\, e^{-\frac{i\hbar k^2}{2m}t}$$

where we have used

$$\langle x | k \rangle = \frac{e^{ikx}}{2\pi}$$

and thus arrive at your equation.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to the time-independent Schrodinger equation for the free particle is 
$e^{ikx}$ and the full time-dependent form is the (unormalized) function
$$
\Psi_k(x,t)=e^{ikx}e^{-iE_k t/\hbar}
$$
where $E_k=\hbar^2 k^2/2m$.

If the possible energies $E_k$ were discrete, the general solution would be a sum over these energies the coefficient $\phi(k)$ giving the amplitude of each $\Psi_k(x,t)$ in the solution.  Thus, in the case of a harmonic oscillator,
$$
\Phi(x,t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k \Psi_k(x,t) \tag{1}
$$
where $\Psi_k(x,t)$ has energy $(k+\frac{1}{2})\hbar\omega$.

In the case of the free particle, there is no restriction of the possible values of $E$, and the possible values are continuous: the sum over discrete values of energy (as examplified in (1)) must be replaced by a continuous sum, i.e an integral
$$
\Phi(x,t)=\int dk \phi(k)\Psi_k(x,t)
$$ 
with coefficients $\phi(k)$ chosen so that the function $\Phi(x,t)$ is normalizable and indeed properly normalized

Answer (score 1):

The time dependence is already encapsulated in $e^{-i\epsilon_k t /\hbar}$.

The $\phi(k)$ are given by the overlap of your state $\psi$  **at time $t=0$** with the momentum eigenstates $|k\rangle$, and by this definition they don't depend on time.